# How to update the height of an AVL TREE after a rotation?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

[image]

I'm trying to implement an AVL TREE and I stumble upon this problem, how to update the height whenever I insert a new node?

I know that I have to update the height of the node all the way up.

For instance, in the image the tree has 2 nodes, 50 and 52. H stands for height, and BF stands for balance factor. After insert the node 51 the and update the heights of all its ancestors (52 and 50) I come across the node 50 that after have its height updated to 3 and BF updated to 2 it becomes unbalanced.

After perform a right left rotation the heights got all messed up. How to update the height correctly after any rotation?

Balance factor = node.right - node.left

```
public void insertTree(String word) {

        if (nodeCount == 0) {

            this.root = new AVLNode(word, 1, 0, null, null, null);

            AVLNode left = new AVLNode(null, null, 0, 0, this.root, null, null);
            AVLNode right = new AVLNode(null, null, 0, 0, this.root, null, null);

            this.root.setLeft(left);
            this.root.setRight(right);

            this.nodeCount++;
            return;
        }

        AVLNode nodeFound = treeSearch(word, this.root);
        AVLNode left = new AVLNode(null, 0, 0, nodeFound, null, null);
        AVLNode right = new AVLNode(null, 0, 0, nodeFound, null, null);

        nodeFound.setWord(word);
        nodeFound.setLeft(left);
        nodeFound.setRight(right);
        nodeFound.setHeight(1);
        nodeFound.setBF(0);

        this.nodeCount++;

        // Update height

        updateTree(nodeFound.getParent());

    }

public void updateTree(AVLNode node) {

        while (node != null) {

            AVLNode nodeParent = node.getParent();

            node.setHeight(height2(node));
            balanceFactor(node);
            // Check if its necessary to do any rotation. Update the ancestor of the node
            balance(node);
            node = nodeParent;
        }

    }

public int height(AVLNode node) {

    int heightLeft = node.getLeft().getHeight();
    int heightRight = node.getRight().getHeight();

    int height = 1 + Math.max(heightLeft, heightRight);

    return height;

}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Looking at your previous questions, it is surprising that although all of them got answers and some were clearly appreciated by the community, none of those answers is marked as accepted. Are they really not the answers you were looking for?